# Get GeoFire to return null if there is no index within radius zone

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

I am building a webapp with angularjs and am using firebase. I am using geofire to return values that are within a given radius of a given lat, lng. It s fully working and returns what I want when there are values in the radius. However, when there are no values in the radius zone it returns nothing. This is a problem because on initial page load I have a spinner that starts and ends when something is returned in a promise.  Is there a way to have geofire return a null value if there are no values in the given radius?

This is the code I am using to retrieve the data:

```
geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
        console.log(key + " entered query at " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");


  console.log(key);

      },function(error) {
        console.log("Promise was rejected with the following error: " + error);
      });
    });
```

The console.log will not run unless something is found that is in the radius zone. I need it to still return something so I know to alert the user there are no businesses in the given area.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

UPDATE:

I added the 'ready' event as well thinking it would trigger the 'key_entered' event but it did not thus leaving me back at square one.

```
var onKeyExitedRegistration = geoQuery.on("key_exited", function(key, location, distance) {
```

console.log(key + " exited query to " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
});

```
geoQuery.on("ready",function() {
  console.log(key + " moved within query to " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `key_entered` event will only fire when a key enters the geo-query. So if no key ever enters the query it will never fire.

To check if *any* keys initially are in the geo-query, you can listen for the `ready` event. This fires after the initial data has loaded, so:

```
var keysEntered = false;
geoQuery.on("key_entered", function(key, location, distance) {
    console.log(key + " entered query at " + location + " (" + distance + " km from center)");
    keysEntered = true;
  },function(error) {
    console.log("Promise was rejected with the following error: " + error);
  });
});
geoQuery.on("ready", function() {
  console.log("initial data has loaded");
  if (!keysEntered) {
    console.log("There was no initial data, so there are no business in range (yet).");
  }
});
```

See the [API reference of Geofire for JavaScript](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-js/blob/master/docs/reference.md#geoqueryoneventtype-callback) for more information.

Comment: thank you for your help but after implementing the ''ready' event it still did not help me.  I need to get some flag that lets me know there is no businesses.

Comment: Such a flag doesn't exist, so you'll have to make your own. I added an example.

Comment: I attempted to make a flag just like that but it seems that when its updated in the 'key ready' function, it is not refelcted in the 'ready'

Comment: There must be something else going on here, that's not showing in the snippets of code you're sharing. Can you set up a jsbin/jsfiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: I found the issue.  I had the flag being set in an embedded promise so it was not being set in time.  Thank you for your help